# Junit: What is the best way to check which test is testing a function in Intellij?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, junit

I am using `IntelliJ` community edition and I need to edit some application which was made in `Java`. In that application some functions are covered with tests.

What is the best way to figure out which test(s) is(are) covering some function?

**Example:** I have function called `function1` and I need to find test which is covering that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use "Navigate | Test" action.